# Не удается получить данные strapi

Tags: nginx, ssl, nextjs, strapi

Как задеплоить NextJs + Strapi + Nginx + SSL? Столкнулся казалось бы с тривиальной задачей и не знаю как решить. Мой `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` выглядит следующим образом:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

На 3000 порту работает NextJS, на 1337 запущен страпи. Вот так выглядит strapi/config/server.js:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool('WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS', false),
  },
});
```

Как мне изменить `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` чтобы я мог достучаться к страпи `/api & /admin`

Я пытался добавить

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

и запросы к апи работали нормально, но вот когда заходил в админку, вылетали ошибки связанные с тем что страпи пытался достучатся к плагинам (фото1) указывая абсолютный путь а поскольку nginx не знает о них то и соответственно возвращается 404 ошибка. Возможно есть способ задать прекфикс для все ссылок связаных со strapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]